# Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat6

I am using Tomcat 6, it was working fine, and suddenly I am getting “Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized” on log, how can I fix this ??

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error. It's just a status log entry that the standard output logging of the tool `procrun` daemon (that runs tomcat as a windows service) was successfully initialized.