# "Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized" flooding my logs

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat5.5

I am working with tomcat 5.5 and Java version 1.6. I was doing well with my servlet exercises, but suddenly when i try to deploy a servlet I get an error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /headerInfo/Header

But i checked my coding everything is working. When I went through a log I saw this error repeatedly:

> Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized

So none of my servlets are not working. What can I do to prevent it? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828897/commons-daemon-procrun-stdout-initialized)

Comment: I found the solution.....as I got to know..there is no single reason for this particular problems...because of various different mistakes this error might occur....in my case..when i was trying to deploy the application manually...instead of WEB-INF name folder i have put WEB_INF..... this is where it went wrong........